Angular Module Dependency Issue: Components in SharedModule Can't Access CoreModule Declarations
I'm encountering an issue with module dependencies in my Angular application. I have a CoreModule where I've declared certain components, services, or pipes. This CoreModule is then imported into the AppModule. However, components declared in other feature modules, which import a SharedModule that also imports CoreModule, cannot access declarations (components, services, pipes) from the CoreModule. Components can only use these declarations if they are declared directly in the AppModule.
Why can't components in feature modules, which import SharedModule, access declarations from CoreModule, and how can I ensure that all modules, including SharedModule, have access to declarations from CoreModule?

Only what you export will be visible to the modules that import it.
So firstly make sure you export CoreModule in the shared module, you need to add it to the exports array of shared module.
Then make sure you export all the feature you want to share outside the module in the exports array of the core module.

yes i know but the problem is caused by a pipe , and the problem is in a components that are not a modules , so i only have two solutions , i return the pipe declaration in shared module and i imported once again in the module  that does not import shared module because shared module has a lot of components i don't need in that module or declare this pipe in app.module.ts so all components can acces to it

@ahmeed import the shared module or core module in the imports array of the standalone component and solve your issue

@ahmeed tree shaking will ensure you use only what you need , if the module is loaded once it's not loaded again, else convert the pipe to standalone

sorry but didn't undrestand  you so well , i export core module in shared module and in app module , the problem that pipe existed in core module is not recognised by certain components that are not in shared and non modules , just regular components and they are not standalone ,but they're declared in shared module , i can't declare them in app module that will create a problems in some modules existing in shared

when i import and export core module in shared module the problem solved but it's not logical since i imported and exported in app.moduke.ts

@ahmeed modules imports exports are not inherited, so even if you add to app modules, it only means, it can be used by the app module declarations, you have to import them separately into each individual module, each module, is its own sphere, we only add features through the imports array

now i undrestand , that's why the pipe in core module is not recognised by other components , and do you know what's the optimal solution for this ? thanks for the help

@ahmeed just import it and use whats needed, else go for a standalone approach for the heavily used components/pipes, since you do not need to import the entire module for a single functionality. but even if you do, angular tree shaking takes care of minimizing the prod bundle, with only whats necessary.

for now it works since i import and export in app module and shared module
i will go for the standalone approach
